# How to change related object to another in Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 entities. First of them has:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "team_id")
    private Team team;
```

And I want to create method, that can change team_id in database to another one.
How can I implement that?
I try to find 2 objects from database by repository methods, and `set` new object to first one.

I tried:

```
  public void fromTo(String from, String to, String playerName) {
        Player player = playerRepo.findByName(playerName);

        Long teamIdOfPlayer = player.getTeam().getId();

        Team teamFrom = teamRepo.findByName(from);

        if (teamFrom.getId().equals(teamIdOfPlayer)) {
            teamRepo.findByName(to).setId(teamIdOfPlayer);
            player.setTeam(teamRepo.findByName(to));
        }
        teamRepo.save(teamFrom);
        playerRepo.save(player);
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried? Try to create a (minimal-reproducible-example)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example]

Comment: updated post @DCTID

Answer (score 0):

Since you use JPA and have a method which gives you a team you can just on your current object set the team and persist the object. JPA ( the JPA provider ) will take care of updating the `team_id`.

Something like this:

```
    MyObject x = ... 
    MyObject x2 = ... 
    x2.setTeam(x.getTeam())
    dao.persist(x2);
```

edit: you added a snippet. Do you run that in a transaction? (I cannot post comments, because of SO)

Comment: i find objects by name, i need @Requestparams to let client change id, by entering other name of Team name.
like /change?from=NAME&to=NAME&whatToTransfer=OBJ_FIELD

Comment: Do you run the above code in a transaction? (does it get committed)?